# How to specify file and path to save a file with R-shiny and shinyFiles?

Tags: r, excel, save, shiny

I am working with R (shiny) and want to save a dataframe as an excel file.
For this purpose I use the "shinyFiles" package so that the user can specify where the excel file is to be stored:

server.R
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyFiles)

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

## ShinyFiles : get the user favorite directory
volumes=c(home = '~/'),
shinyDirChoose(input, 'dir', roots=volumes, filetypes = c('','xlsx')),
output$dir.res <- renderPrint({parseDirPath(volumes, input$dir)}),

## Button to save the file
observeEvent(input$button.save, {

## A standard file name
A <- "name"
B <- "family
if( input$text == "File name..." ) outFile <- paste( A, "_", B, ".xlsx", sep="" )

## Append the path to the file name
outFile <- paste( parseDirPath(volumes, input$path.out), outFile, sep="/" )

## The data to be saved
x=seq(from=0,to=10,by=1)
d = data.frame( x )
write.xlsx( d, outFile )
}
```

and the ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(

## Choose the output directory
shinyDirButton("dir", "Choose directory", "Upload"),
## Choose the output file name
textInput("text", label = "", value = "File name..."),
## Save the data
actionButton("button.save", "Save the file"),
## Give the path selected
verbatimTextOutput("dir.res")
)))
```

Despite all the examples found for similar questions I have been trying around for 2h (shame..) and will be thankful for help

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. `shinyFiles` is supposed to be `A shiny extension for server side file access`, and not for selecting client side files. To save a file, just use a normal `downloadButton` together with associated `downloadHandler`.

Comment: I am a newbie in R shiny, so a misunderstanding is possible, I would however want that the user be able to choose where he is going to save the file, which is, if I am correct, different from what the downloadButton does.

Comment: File download is generally handled by the web browser, and it's not for HTML to control (there is a security concern as a webpage is not supposed to see your local hard drive). If your user is using Firefox, they can do this http://www.pcworld.com/article/217112/missing_downloads.html but generally this is very browser-specific

Comment: I see, but my R-shiny script is going to run locally on a computer, and not on a server. I look for a way that is not browser-dependant.

Comment: If your code is to run on a computer, and user is going to select a download location on the same computer, `shinyFiles` should work. I'll try it and give an answer if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a working example. Again, this assumes that you run the app on your own computer, and users are allowed to access folders on this computer. You can set the root folder where user is allowed to save files (see `UserFolder`, user will be able to choose any subfolder of this root)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(xlsx)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Example"),
  shinySaveButton("save", "Save file", "Save file as ...", filetype=list(xlsx="xlsx"))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    volumes <- c("UserFolder"="D:/Data")
    shinyFileSave(input, "save", roots=volumes, session=session)
    fileinfo <- parseSavePath(volumes, input$save)
    data <- data.frame(a=c(1,2))
    if (nrow(fileinfo) > 0) {
      write.xlsx(data, as.character(fileinfo$datapath))
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```