# R shinyFiles shinySaveButton "Create new folder" + Button Causes Error

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using the code from the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517199/how-to-specify-file-and-path-to-save-a-file-with-r-shiny-and-shinyfiles), which I've reposted here as a working example.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(xlsx)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Example"),
  shinySaveButton("save", "Save file", "Save file as ...", filetype=list(xlsx="xlsx"))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    volumes <- c("UserFolder"="C:/")
    shinyFileSave(input, "save", roots=volumes, session=session)
    fileinfo <- parseSavePath(volumes, input$save)
    data <- data.frame(a=c(1,2))
    if (nrow(fileinfo) > 0) {
      write.xlsx(data, as.character(fileinfo$datapath))
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I get the following error when I attempt to create a folder with the + button in the "Create new folder" sub-menu:

```
Warning: Error in dir.create: invalid 'path' argument
Stack trace (innermost first):
    58: dir.create
    57: dirCreate
    56: observerFunc
     1: runApp
```

However, I get the correct behaviour when I hit Enter instead of using the + button.  Did some searching but couldn't find anything related.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Strange, I get the same error when setting "C:/" to getwd(). I have no experience with the shinyFiles package, but it feels like a bug. f no one else is able to answer, maybe post it here https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles/issues ?

Comment: @Florian Thanks for testing - I'll let this sit here for a while and then post it to github as you suggested.

Comment: Im pretty sure its due to the attempt to directly write to `c:/`. E.g. `c:/Shiny` should work after you created that directory. Writing directly to `c:/` would  require executing that command with admin rights. I doubt that would be desired behaviour and i therefore dont think it is a bug. Any reason you directly want to write to `c:/` and not to a subfolder?

Comment: @BigDataScientist: The only reason I chose "C:\" was so I could access all subdirectories on my laptop.  In my tests, I navigated to the Desktop and attempted to create a folder with the results stated above - successful using Enter, not successful using +.  Note that even if I start in a folder that shouldn't require admin rights like the Desktop, I get the same behaviour.

Comment: ah ok. You might want to add that to the question. One last idea from my side: Check what `observe(print(file.exists(volumes)` returns,...