# Exporting/Saving output to a text file in a folder location

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I want to create a file using various inputs and export the inputs in a text file in a local folder, say in /file/ in the project directory. I have the following working app.

```
require(shiny)

runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Creating frile"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("var",
                label = "Drops",
                choices = c("Op1", "Op2", "Op3", "Op4"),
                selected = "Op1"),
    sliderInput("range",
                label = "Slide to select",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0, 100)),
    actionButton("button", "Export file")
  ),
  mainPanel(htmlOutput("text")
  )
),

server = function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderUI({
    str1 <- paste("You have selected:", input$var)
    str2 <- paste("The range that goes between:",
                  input$range[1], "to", input$range[2])
    HTML(paste(str1, str2, sep = '<br/>'))
  })
  
}

)

)
```

What I want to achive by the action button is: it will save a text file in a project folder location, e.g. /outputtext/. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: what do you want to save more precisely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify file and path to save a file with R-shiny and shinyFiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517199/how-to-specify-file-and-path-to-save-a-file-with-r-shiny-and-shinyfiles)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent If you run this app, you will see two lines like this: `You have selected: Op1
The range that goes between: 0 to 100`. I want to push the action button to save these two lines in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```r
observeEvent(input$button, {
  str1 <- paste("You have selected:", input$var)
  str2 <- paste("The range that goes between:",
                input$range[1], "to", input$range[2])
  writeLines(c(str1, str2), "path/to/file.txt")
})
```